# How to use Apple's Passwords for Amazon and AWS?

Tags: password

I'm using Apple's new Password manager, and while it definitely has some rough edges compared to 1Password I'm overall happy with it.

I'm a developer, and I use both Amazon's main store as well as Amazon Web Services. Amazon have made a recent change to split those two logins, so that the credentials, MFA etc are separate. I can't get Apple's password manager to handle that. For Amazon's store the login is at https://www.amazon.com/ap/signin, and for AWS it's at https://signin.aws.amazon.com/signin. When I try to add separate passwords for those, macOs Passwords insists on grouping them both under the same entry (labeled amazon.com), and this means that I can't add separate passwords or MFA for them. Since these used to be the same user, the username is the same for both of them.

Any ideas how I might achieve this?

Comment: Use a 3rd party password manage like KeePassXC. It’s open source, cross platform (macOS, Windows, FreeBSD, Linux) and has mobile clients.  Works with all cloud storage providers (OneDrive, DropBox, etc).

Comment: @Colin Have you tried simply adding the second password - even though it is grouped the same (as amazon.com), they should still be stored seperately. When you go to login it should popup the right one - and if not, you can click just below the incorrect one to be able to choose other stored passwords.

Comment: @jksoegaard I wouldn't mind having to choose, the problem is that I want 2FA on both of them, and they have to be separate. Apple doesn't let me assign different 2FA tokens to the separate websites. They really need to be separate entries, but I'm not sure if that's possible.

Comment: @Allan I'd rather not change my whole password strategy just for this one site.

Comment: @Colin Have you tried adding seperate entries? - It seems to work OK for me (I'm using both Amazon and AWS). Otherwise perhaps consider using a different 2MFA app for one of those - for example Authy on Mac or similar.

Comment: @jksoegaard Thanks, I actually managed to get separate entries by deleting the existing one entirely and recreating them both from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to simply add two different accounts. Even though they are grouped the same (as amazon.com), they can still be used separately.

When you go to login it should popup the right one - and if not, you can click just below the incorrect one to be able to choose other stored passwords.

Note: It seems the easiest way forward here was to delete the existing account information, and them simply add two separate entries one after another - in the same manner as when just adding a single entry.

Comment: When I delete the accounts, I can create one fine, but when I try to create the second one, a popup error shows 
> *Password Already Exists*
> A password for “$EMAIL” on “(null)” already exists.

Comment: Amazon followed by AWS won't work.
However if I create the AWS entry first, then I can create a second entry for Amazon successfully.